# How to restrict third closed source process to read only own folders on Linux?

Tags: privacy, permissions, spyware, third-party

I have DropBox, Opera, Steam and others third closed software on my ArchLinux. I don't trust them, so I want limit its to read only its own folders aiming security and privacy protection.

Comment: How to migrate this question?

Comment: Ok i will do it.

Comment: Do post a link to the new question here, so other people can find it for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea that comes to mind is inspired by the way Android handles this: create a new user account for each app.

When you want to install a new untrusted program, first create a new user for it. Next, install the program as that user, in that user's home directory. Launch the app through scripts like `su dropbox; dropboxd` and set the permissions such that apps can't read each other's files. Make your login user a member of all these groups so you can still read the files.

*Note: this is an off-the-top-of-my-head idea, I have no idea how feasible it is. It may take a fair amount of work to build a workstation that behaves this way while still being moderately user-friendly.*

Comment: I edited to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Although it is a correct answer. It takes a lot of work to be implemented (as you yourself said). And it involves reinstalling everything in different places from the originals.